# system.log showing <config/> and no other messages

Tags: magento-1, log

I am working locally on an xampp setup.  I am trying to debug a problem using `Mage::log()` but nothing is showing up in my system.log file.

Every page load just gives me two lines of output:

> 2014-03-20T02:46:58+00:00 DEBUG (7): 
>   2014-03-20T02:47:03+00:00 DEBUG (7):

No matter where I put `Mage::log()` I still get these two lines.

Comment: You might want to include what you are passing as an argument to `log()`, what file you are doing this in, and what your expected result it. By itself, `log()` will only log the info you pass to it.

Comment: Even if I pass a string I get nothing.  I have tried it in loads of files including the 2column-left.phtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove your `Mage::log()` statement and see if the `system.log` still gets populated with `<config />`. I have a feeling that it comes from somewhere else.

**Here is how the logging works.**
In `Mage::log` there is this code

```
if (!self::$_isDeveloperMode && !$logActive && !$forceLog) {
    return;
}
```

This means that if you don't have the developer mode on, and the logging is not active and you don't pass the 4th parameter to the log method that tells it to force the log, nothing will get logged.

**What you can do**.  Any one of the following is enough.

1. Enable the developer mode. You should always develop with developer mode on.  Add this line to the `httpd.conf`: `SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1`.
2. Activate the log from `System->Configuration->Developer->Log Settings`.
3. Force the logging to make sure it always works even if the log is not active or developer mode is off. Call the log method like this: `Mage::log('Text to log', null, '', true)`. Notice the 4th parameter set to true.